# How to Search if a File Name exists in a text document?

Tags: c#, file-io

I am making an app in C# where I am searching if the file exists in the text file or not. If it does not exist then, it would add it in the text file and then append it in a List. But, for some reason the list only takes one file and ends at that point. So, can someone help me with what is the problem in this foreach loop?

```
static void CheckNewFile()
    {
        string path_f = @"File_Address_where_Text_file_exists";
        var new_file = new List<string>();
        if (!File.Exists(path_f))   # Checking if the text file exists or not and then creating it
        {
            var myFile = File.Create(path_f);
            myFile.Close();
        }
        DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(@"File_Address_in_which_Files_need_to_be_searched");
        FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("AC" + "*" + "*.*" + "AC"); # Format of the file to be searched
        foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir) # foreach for the files in the directory
        {
            string fullName = foundFile.FullName;
            int flag = 0;
            var lines = File.ReadLines(path_f);

            foreach (var line in lines) # Reading line by line and checking if the file exists in the text file before
            {
                if (String.Equals(line, fullName))
                {
                    flag += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (flag < 1)
            {
                if (new FileInfo(path_f).Length == 0)    # File Address is appended in the File
                {
                    //TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path_f);
                    //tw.WriteLine(fullName);
                    //tw.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    //using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path_f, true))
                    //{
                    //    tw.WriteLine(fullName);
                    //}
                }
                new_file.Add(fullName.ToString()); # Adding File Address to the list
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last break. It is causing the program flow to leave the enclosing foreach loop with the file names.

Comment: Thanks bro  u r the best

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster mentioned, you're breaking out of your loop early in the `if` block.

However, there isn't really a need for the flag (or loop or if block) at all. Your method could be simplified greatly by using a little `System.Linq` and just using `Directory` to find the new files by comparing their paths to the contents of the input file.

For example:

```
static List<string> CheckForNewFiles(string filePath, string searchDir, 
    string searchPattern)
{
    // Create file if it doesn't exist
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) using (File.Create(filePath)) ;

    // Get list of files that match search pattern which aren't contained in our file
    var newFiles = Directory
        .GetFiles(searchDir, searchPattern)
        .Where(match => !File.ReadLines(filePath).Contains(match))
        .ToList();

    // Add the new file paths to our file
    File.AppendAllLines(filePath, newFiles);

    // Return the list of new files (?)
    return newFiles;
}
```

In use it migth look something like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Checking for new files...");

    var newFiles = CheckForNewFiles(@"c:\temp\paths.txt", @"c:\temp\temp", "*.png");

    Console.WriteLine($"{newFiles.Count} files found since last search.");

    if (newFiles.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" -> " + string.Join(Environment.NewLine + " -> ", newFiles));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will implement it.